# OutOfMemoryError in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, out-of-memory, netty

Too many OutOfMemoryError has occurred and stopped cassandra service.

```
     WARN [New I/O worker #22] 2016-11-03 10:38:15,083 Slf4JLogger.java (line 76) Unexpected exception in the selector loop.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
        at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:658)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:306)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SocketReceiveBufferAllocator.newBuffer(SocketReceiveBufferAllocator.java:64)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SocketReceiveBufferAllocator.get(SocketReceiveBufferAllocator.java:44)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:62)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone help me to find rootcause? 
I'm using cassandra-2.0.9 and netty-3.6.6.Final.jar.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to obtain a heap dump and inspect it.